# Touch Screen Preventing Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have a Lenovo touch screen desktop where I am running a touch based website. The problem is that browsers (Chrome) seem to freeze when I click with eight fingers and try to scroll around. The browser locks up. So I'm attempting to create a function with jQuery that will only register one single touch event.

Here is what I have now:

```
        var isTouched = false;
        var $document = $(document);
        $document.on('touchstart', function (e) {
            if (!isTouched) {
                isTouched = true;
                console.log('start: ' + isTouched);

                $document.on('touchend', function() {
                    if (isTouched) {
                        isTouched = false;
                        console.log('end: ' + isTouched);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Which works ok, but it prevents me from scrolling, and the `touchend` seems to be firing when I lift the first finger off the screen. The expected behavior would be for `touchend` only to fire when I lift the finger off the screen that caused the `touchstart`. Any suggestions for creating a function which will only register one `touchstart` at a time and allow scrolling (i.e. not ignore the `touchmove`).